# C++ arbitary function deserialization

Tags: c++, function, templates, io, deserialization

**Problem**

Assume there is a set of different functions. Each of there functions may be a member function of some object, and may take an arbitary number of arguments. For simplicity sake lets assume that each function has no more than 8 arguments of `int`, `double` or `std::string` types. For example:

```
class MyClass{
public:
  void DoA(int i);
  void DoB(double d, int i);
};

class YourClass{
public:
  void DoC(std::string s);
  void DoD(int i1, int i2, int i3);
};
```

Lets assume there is a file containing a series of records about functions. Each record contains name of the function to be called, its arguments values and pointer to the object for the member function. I need a way to read all this data from the file and execute functions in correct order with correct arguments.

It is okay to have names of the functions hard-coded, for example, but adding a new function to a libary should be as easy as possible.

**Motivation**

This is a part of roguelike game project I'm trying to create, specifically a save/load game system. Once a player tries to save his game, all events that have not yet occurred must be saved too, and next time the player loads the game events should be loaded and scheduled properly. Since roguelike is clearly needs a lot of space to expand, I don't want to make any assumptions about the functions type.

Comment: Why don't you just use a serialization library???

Comment: Since you didn't ask the question, it's hard to answer. Anyway, this design is bad; use an embedded script language (I'm not advocating Lua, not at all) and forget about this monstrous concept. Or merge to Gamedev SE, and then I'll answer you.

Comment: The question is how to implement such thing. @VladLazarenko I don't know any such library and so far I've tried to record saves in XML.

Comment: See [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/libs/serialization/) for a general-purpose serialization library. I'm not sure what you mean to "serialize a function" though.

Comment: Multiple signatures is hard. Better to allow each function to consume a single argument, namely a string, and then let *that* function do the parsing.

Comment: @KerrekSB That sounds like a very good idea for my purposes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea:

```
class Foo
{
    void f1_impl(double, char, int);
    void f2_impl(int, int);

    void func1(std::string s)
    {
        double d;
        char   c;
        int    i;

        std::tie(d, c, i) = parse<double, char, int>(std::move(s));

        f1_impl(d, c, i);
   }

   void func2(std::string s)
   {
        // similarly
   }
};

std::unordered_map<std::string, void (Foo::*)(std::string)> const functions
{  { "function1", &Foo::func1 },
   { "function2", &Foo::func2 },
};
```

Input file:

```
function1 1.250000,'a',2815
function2 12,-80
function2 99,111
```

Parsing:

```
Foo x;

for (std::string line; std::getline(inputfile, line); )
{
    std::string f, a;

    if (!(std::istringstream(line) >> f >> a)) { /* error */ }

    (x.*functions[f])(a);
}
```

Comment: That's still hardly usable for me.

Comment: @Saage: Note that you could make `func1` etc. generic, as a template, like `func_wrap<&Foo::f1_impl>(std::string)` etc., since the content is always the same.